# Detect if any dialog is opened

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have created single instance application. It accepts command line arguments and process them. If application is already running and some dialog ( open file or message box ) is opened. Now if i try to pass command line argument i need to check if dialog is shown or not. So I added this code.

```
        if (!Application.Current.MainWindow.IsActive)
        {

            Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
        }

        if (Keyboard.FocusedElement != null)
        {
        // If focused element is not null it means no other dialog is shown.
        // safe to go.
        }
```

Ideal was like , if focused element is not null then it means focus is inside window and no other dialog is shown.

In normal scenarios when window is not minimized this code works fine. but if window is minimized then condition fails as keyboard focus is not in window.

Do u find any solution which will be generic ? I can achieve this by adding flags before each dialog box. but I have more than 10 dialog boxes. In future i may add more dialog boxes.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code for launching the dialog box

Comment: MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Hello World");

Comment: What is the code around that to create multiple MessageBoxes?

Comment: As its single instance application , executing it once again fire up same code. Scenario is like , if use tries to save some file we are showing save file dialog, suppose user minimize and tries to open some file by double clicking on file present on file system ; it shows same dialog because document is not save , and before opening i have checked whether previous document is saved or not...

Answer (score 7):

Very old question but I've recently faced a similar issue. 
Here is how I solved it:

```
public static bool IsAnyModalOpened()
{
    return Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Any(IsModal);
}

public static bool IsModal(this Window window)
{
    var fieldInfo = typeof(Window).GetField("_showingAsDialog", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return fieldInfo != null && (bool)fieldInfo.GetValue(window);
}
```